# hostgator not recognizing urls.py of Django project

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, shared-hosting

I am working within the File Manager of Hostgator and have already set up a Django project which displays "It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page." Following this, I ftp'ed my local Django project (which works fine on the local server) into File Manager and stored it into a temp folder, copying over the changes to the urls.py, views.py, and settings.py files of the new Django project along the settings path.

However, nothing appears to be changing on the website - it's still on the "Congratulations" page. I've tried moving various templates into different places to see if it responds, but that doesn't appear to be doing the trick. Thoughts?

Comment: You can't just deploy a Django project by copying your files to the server. See the [deployment documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/). Looking at the Hostgator site though, it doesn't really seem to be a suitable server for Django.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read documentation about how to [manage your project](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi#shared-managing) on the hostgator servers